# passing a multidimenional array through ajax via json with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to do form validation all through ajax. I sanitize the form, and pass it through to a php file that will sanitize and validate the form. If there are any errors I want it to change the field border a different color and display an error message below the form (this I can do no problem).

Its just from this php file, it will be called through ajax, but needs to return an array like:

```
$errors = array();
$errors['text'] = array(array('name'=>'address','messages'=>'Enter an address'),array('name'=>'phone','messages'=>'Enter a phone'));
$errors['select'] = array(array('name'=>'company','messages'=>'Enter a company name'));
```

Resulting in an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [text] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => address
                    [messages] => Enter an address
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => phone
                    [messages] => Enter a phone
                )

        )

    [select] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => company
                    [messages] => Enter a company name
                )

        )

)
```

Now at the end of that file if I have

```
$data = $errors;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then I will have encoded that array into json, and it means I can pass it through to the jquery script.

```
serialize = $('#form').serialize();
$.ajax({        
    type    : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    url     : '//'+base_url+'/ajax/form-validation.php',
    data    : serialize,
    success : function(data) {

    }
});
```

The part I am not sure about is how do I get all the data back from the array under success.
I want to do the equivalent of:

```
foreach($errors['text'] as $e) text($e);
foreach($errors['select'] as $e) select($e);
```

So for the 'text' variables they would pass the name and message variables through the text() function, and the 'select' variables would do the same through the select() function.

But how is this achieved though json and jquery?

Comment: `data.select` and `data.text` ?

Comment: whats the foreach function for jquery?

Comment: you can use `.each()` or a simple for loop like `var selectdata=data.select; for(var i = 0 ; i<selectdata.length;i++){selectdata[i].name}` just follow that format to get each item of each index

Comment: `data.select.each(function(){})` - how are the variables created for each one here?

Comment: You might need to parse the return as json first though, or set the data type to be json so jquery automatically converts it into a JavaScript object

Comment: `data.select.each(function(i,v){//where i = name or message and v = company or Enter a company name})` hope this helps. `i = index , v = value of that index`